# How to use instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby

Hi guys wondering if anything like this was possible in ruby. Trying to use an instance variable for a conditional constant. I believe this isn't allowed is there another way of doing it?

```
class test

  if @init_bool
    VAR = 10
  else
    VAR = 15
  end
  def initialize(test_bool)
    @init_bool = test_bool
  end
end
```

Comment: No, constant on a class cannot depend on an instance variable. Because the class exists before the instance is created and there might be multiple differentiation instances. That doesn’t make any sense. Would you mind to elaborate on what you actually try to achieve?

Comment: Right now I am using a Constant variable. Recently it changed where I have to check the instance variable and change the constant based on that. How can I go about updating the constant using the instance variable

Comment: If a value depends on another instance variable then that value is not constant anymore because when the instance variable changes then the constant would need to change too. And constants are by definition unchangeable (constant)... Sound like a simple method should solve your problem.

Comment: @EthanKulla "How can I go about updating the constant using the instance variable" - just don't :) The term "constant" means it is something, um, constant. Sadly, Ruby does allow updating constants, but this is an _extremely_ bad idea. Could you please provide more context on the task you're trying to solve? There might be plenty of better ways to do it than trying to update a constant from the initializer...

Comment: So im updating some code and I need to modify a constant list based on some feature flag. Because the feature flag takes a variable from the initialize as a param, I would like it so I dont have to change everything else so it works with a method instead of a constant. My goal is to update the constant based on some conditional. It should be temporary until the feature flag is removed. So maybe updating a constant will work for me?

Comment: No, this does not work, but not for the reason you think: the problem is that identifiers in class definitions must be constants, i.e. must start with a capital letter. If you change the name of the class from `test` to `Test`, it will work.

Comment: Figured out a way around it, thanks for your help guys. Realized my original thinking was just illogical. Still a newbie with Ruby :D

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly shouldn't do it (and even more likely you actually want to do something else instead) - you can do so, if you really, really insist on it.

```
class Foo
end

class Test < Foo
  def self.new x
    y= super 
    self.const_set :VAR, (y.instance_variable_get(:@init_bool) ? 10 : 15)
    y
  end
  
  def initialize test_bool
    @init_bool = test_bool
  end
end
```

Then you would get this behaviour:

```
> Test.new false
=> #<Test:0x00007f9b519ea4f0 @init_bool=false>

> Test::VAR
=> 15

> Test.new true
=> #<Test:0x00007f9b51982e40 @init_bool=true>

> Test::VAR
=> 10
```

And you would also receive some warnings for every additional instance of Test you create (which is good - while the warnings won't stop you from what you are doing, they at least inform you about this unusual behaviour).